# django form errors prints __all__

Tags: django, forms, printing

This code in the default login template:

```
{{ form.errors }}
```

Produces this html output when the account is inactive:

```
<ul class="errorlist">
  <li>__all__
    <ul class="errorlist">
      <li>This account is inactive.</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Why does it print the string **_*all*_**?

I'm using the development version by the way.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Ah, I should have used:

```
{{ form.non_field_errors }}
```

instead

Answer (score 5):

If you, like me, still want to display ALL errors at once, you can loop over form.errors.items.

This line:

```
{{ form.errors }}
```

Becomes this: (or similar)

```
<ul class="errorlist">
    {% for key, value in form.errors.items %}
    <li>{% if key != '__all__' %}{{ key }} {% endif %}{{ value }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```