# Display ValidationError In Ajax

Tags: django, ajax

I'm trying to display ValidationErrors using ajax. I've read many posts about this and tried many things but can't get it to work. I thiiinnnkkk ValidationErrors are passed as a dictionary and that they need to have `json.dumps` or `.as_json()` called on them before they are passed to ajax.

Here is some of my code:

forms.py

```
raise forms.ValidationError('Please enter a number greater than 100')
```

views.py

```
if form.is_valid():
    [...]
else:
    # i've tried this
    error_dict= {'status':'form-invalid','form-errors':form.errors}
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(error_dict),content_type="application/json", status_code=400)
    # and this
    data = {'error':form.errors.as_json(), 'is_valid': False}
    return JsonResponse(data, status_code=400)
    # and more
```

ajax

```
error: function (data, xhr, errmsg, err) {
    $('.error').html(data.form-errors)
},
```

--edit--

console.log:

```
{error: {…}, is_valid: false}
    error:
        __all__: Array(1)
            0: "You cannot lock a lesson when the following lesson is unlocked"
            length: 1
          __proto__: Object
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error details are actually store in `data['error']` not `data.form-errors`. You data will also have another item `is_valid`. The response data structure can be inspected by console logging `data` in ajax error. According to the structure access values and assign to elements.

In ajax error:

```
error: function (data, xhr, errmsg, err) {
    console.log(data)
    console.log(data.responseJSON)

    // according to the structure of data access error value and assign
    $('.error').html(data['error'])
},
```

in views.py `form.errors` should be passed. in JsonResponse() we need to pass a dictionary.

> The first parameter, data, should be a dict instance. [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/request-response/#jsonresponse-objects)

```
if form.is_valid():
    [...]
else:
    data = {'error':form.errors, 'is_valid': False}
    return JsonResponse(data, status_code=400)
```

In your script if you `console.log('data.responseJSON')` you could see something like this

[image]

In the above image I can access the error message for the field 'fname' as `data.responseJSON.error.fname[0]`

Comment: Thank you, but I am also having trouble passing the ValidationError data from my views.py to ajax

Comment: @Brenden `form.errors` itself is a dictionary. So `data = {'error':form.errors, 'is_valid': False}`. I'm refering to `JsonResponse()` not `HttpResponse()`. please verify that you have kept only `JsonResponse()`

Comment: Hmm. I have ```data = {'error':form.errors, 'is_valid': False}``` ```return JsonResponse(data, status=400)``` in views.py and ```$('.error').html(data['error'])``` in ajax but it's displaying ```undefined```. I've also tried ```return HttpResponse(json.dumps(data), content_type="application/json", status=400)``` and several other variations

Comment: Thank you. I'm very close now, I think the last thing holding me up is that ```error``` contains an array called ```__all__```. I added the console.log to the bottom of my original post.

Comment: @Brenden look into this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5221137/django-form-errors-prints-all/16886432) . From [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/forms/validation/) `Note that any errors raised by your Form.clean() override will not be associated with any field in particular. They go into a special “field” (called __all__), which you can access via the non_field_errors() method if you need to.`